# Theming with ActionBarSherlock not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I can't seem to get the theming of the action buttons working either using ABS or the standard ActionBar. Despite using `selectableItemBackground` in my theme, it still uses the blue highlight instead of the requested red one. However, it seems to work fine for the discard button in the SearchView (see attached images).

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, anyone know what?!

Pressed Action Buttons use this highlight:
[image: Showing the wrong highlight]

When they should be using this one:
[image: Showing the right highlight]

This is the style I'm using:

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.EditText</item>
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background</item>
</style>
```

**UPDATE**

using `<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background</item>` seems to work, but this isn't what Nick Butcher's [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) on theming uses. Is this acceptable/will it break anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That article was written for Android 3.0 and the attribute changed for Android 4.0 which is why you are seeing the difference in behavior.

Using `actionBarItemBackground` is now the correct method of changing the background of action items.

If you're using ActionBarSherlock remember that you need both `android`-prefixed and non-prefixed version in the theme for it to work on all API levels.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for that. Do you know what style I need to use to theme the Overflow menu items?

Comment: As I saw in the source of [themes.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml#L345), `actionBarItemBackground` points to `selectableItemBackground`, so in my understanding, changing `selectableItemBackground` should also change `actionBarItemBackground`. No ?

Comment: Yes. But `selectableItemBackground` covers more than just the action items now. Use whichever is appropriate.